# How do I create additional users connected to my Cognito Forms account and give them access to entries for their specific forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I had created an online booking form for products. I should display the order to the admin. I need to add a user to view the entries in my form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You can add new users to your Organization by inviting them. This can be done under the 'Users' area of your Organization Settings. Once invited, the user will get an email with an invitation link. They can use the link to add an already existing user account to your Organization or they can create a new one. You can learn more about adding or inviting users in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/193/account--organizations/user-management/adding-or-inviting-users).

Once your user has been added to your Organization you can set up the users specific permissions. You can restrict the users so that they can only view entries for a form, without the ability to edit the form. You can also block the users ability to view forms at all. You can learn more about setting up user permission levels in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/164/account--organizations/user-management/user-permission-levels) as well.